# How to get exception related to TypeError when user input more arguments than the function can handle

Tags: python, python-3.x, try-except

I'm trying to implemente an try/exception in my code and I want the Exception to print "Error" when the user input more arguments than the function is expecting.

The problem is that my code below doesn't print the "Error" msg, but it prints an standard msg:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: text_analyzer() takes from 0 to 1 positional arguments but 2 were given
```

Since it's a TypeError, I've used this option in my Exception but is still doesn't work.

Here is the code

```
import string


def text_analyzer(text=None):
    try:
        ucase = 0
        lcase = 0
        punc = 0
        space = 0
        while not text:
            text = input("What is the text to analyze?")
        for letter in text:
            if letter in string.ascii_uppercase:
                ucase += 1
            elif letter in string.ascii_lowercase:
                lcase += 1
            elif letter in string.punctuation:
                punc += 1
            elif letter in string.whitespace:
                space += 1
        size = len(text)
        print(
            f"The text contains {size} characteres:\n"
            f"- {ucase} upper letters\n"
            f"- {lcase} lower letters\n"
            f"- {punc} punctuation marks\n"
            f"- {space} spaces\n"
        )
    except TypeError:
        print("Error")
    except Exception:
        print("Error")
```

Comment: You haven't shown how you are calling `text_analyzer`; this kind of error occurs *before* you get into the function.  (Wrong number of arguments is *not* a TypeError.)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I found out that I should use the try/exception outside the function to work.

A better solution that I found is using *args. It worked for me.

Here is the code fixed:

```
import string


def text_analyzer(text=None, *args):
    ucase = 0
    lcase = 0
    punc = 0
    space = 0

    if len(args) > 0:
        print("Error")
        return
    while not text:
        text = input("What is the text to analyze?")
    for letter in text:
        if letter in string.ascii_uppercase:
            ucase += 1
        elif letter in string.ascii_lowercase:
            lcase += 1
        elif letter in string.punctuation:
            punc += 1
        elif letter in string.whitespace:
            space += 1
    size = len(text)
    print(
        f"The text contains {size} characteres:\n"
        f"- {ucase} upper letters\n"
        f"- {lcase} lower letters\n"
        f"- {punc} punctuation marks\n"
        f"- {space} spaces\n"
    )
```